# ssh with rsa key asks for password

Tags: ssh, sshd

I have a server with Ubuntu 14.04 x64 operation system.

Part of my `sshd_config` file ([entire file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9124055/)):

```
Port 2202
Protocol 2
PermitRootLogin without-password
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      /etc/ssh/keys/%u/authorized_keys
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
#PasswordAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
```

In folder `/etc/ssh/keys` each system user has its own folder with `authorized_keys` file:

```
ls -l /etc/ssh/keys
drw------- 2 test.com  test.com   4096 Nov 20 06:53 test.com
drw------- 2 root      root       4096 Nov 20 02:29 root
```

The permissions of these authorized_keys files are correct:

```
ls -l /etc/ssh/keys/*
/etc/ssh/keys/test.com:
total 4
-r-------- 1 test.com test.com 960 Nov 20 07:17 authorized_keys

/etc/ssh/keys/root:
total 4
-r-------- 1 root root 395 Nov 20 02:29 authorized_keys
```

I have the same public id_rsa in root's and test.com's authorized_keys file.
I can login with root through ssh, but with test.com I am prompted for password.

Here is the debug info when trying to connect with test.com user:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/Ivan/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Ivan/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

When I try to login with root I succeed:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/Ivan/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

I have Googled a lot of things. Couldn't find anything that solves my problem.

I have a script which creates system users using `useradd` command and these users are without passwords by default. 
I've found that system users without password may not login through ssh so I added password to test.com user. Didn't work.

I saw that `UsePAM yes` may be a problem. I set it to `UsePAM no`. Didn't work.

And yes, I did `service ssh restart` after each change to the `sshd_config` file.

I think I've tried everything and now I am clueless.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You *probably* want to use PAM. Most everyone does.

I am a little bit curious about `sshd_config` where you have your authorized keys. The default is `AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys`. Have you made any changes to `ssh_config` (not `sshd_config`)?

Comment: No. I have changed only sshd_keys. There I changed the location of the keys at `AuthorizedKeysFile ` directive

Comment: What kind of access does Ivan have to /Users/Ivan/.ssh/id_rsa? Could it be that root can read that file but not Ivan?

Comment: Try more debugging msgs. `ssh -vvv ...`.

Comment: and how do you copy your key to the server? `vi .ssh/authorized_keys` or doing `ssh-copy-id root@server`? maybe if you do the first one you made a typo

Comment: Check the server logs (I think the right log file is `/var/log/auth.log`, but check any log file that gets modified by the login attempt). Edit your question and copy-paste the entries that are generated by the login attempt.

Comment: @YoMismo I am using Ivan as client user (the one that connects to the server) and I just change the ssh user@ip... I use the same key for both users so I have access to this key. @maniat1k I am sure I do not have a typo because I tried to move the content from `root/authorized_keys` to `test.com/authorized_keys`, they are identical. @slm I used -vvv and I showed the important output at my question. @Gilles when try to connect nothing is showing in auth.log. When I am prompted for password I cancel the login attempt and I see this result: `sshd[9138]: Connection closed by *.*.*.* [preauth]`

Comment: There is something that I don't have very clear. Are you using the -i parameter in your ssh command to specify the public key to use? Both root and Ivan are using the same public key (not a copy, the same path `/Users/Ivan/.ssh/id_rsa`). Does both users have the same private key in their respective ~/.ssh? what are the permissions of Ivan's .ssh/id_rsa or the name of the private key to that public key?

Comment: You really got it wrong. `/Users/Ivan/.ssh/id_rsa` is my local private key owned by user Ivan (my local user). On the server I have the public key of Ivan user for both users root and test.com with proper permissions. I can login with root, I cannot login with test.com (prompted for password)

Comment: Could you try with 700 permissions to both `/etc/ssh/keys/test.com` and `/etc/ssh/keys/test.com/authorized_keys`?

Comment: Nothing changed. Again prompted for password.

Comment: Could you backup `/etc/ssh/keys/test.com/authorized_keys` and copy `/etc/ssh/keys/root/authorized_keys` to `/etc/ssh/keys/test.com`, modify user to test.com and see what happens?

Comment: I have already tried this. It doesn't work

Comment: You indicate "I have the same public id_rsa in root's and test.com's authorized_keys file.", yet the authorized_keys files are different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and found that SELinux was preventing read access to `/usr/bin/sshd` when trying to remote in for some users. Typically for users that don't have a home folder under `/home/`. You can run

```
cat /var/log/messages | grep -i ssh
```

*on the target server*, and you should see a similar line indicating the error:

```
<Date/Time> <hostname> python: SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/sshd from read access on the file authorized_keys.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012
If you believe that sshd should be allowed read access on the authorized_keys file by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# 
ausearch -c 'sshd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-sshd#012# semodule -i my-sshd.pp#012`
```

You can edit the SELinux permissions to allow ssh connections or simply turn it off (less secure) to get around this.

Comment: System in question is Ubuntu, which by default doesn't use SELinux.

Comment: I had been happy to reformat your post, but I couldn't decide in the middle, where is a new line starting... if you want to show a fixed font, prefix the line with four spaces. Could you please make it good?

Comment: That is because the error in the log is a single line. Not multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

sshd is very picky when it comes to permissions!

It seems that the directory permissions of `/etc/ssh/keys/test.com/` are wrong! Currently the directory is read/write but may not be entered.
`chmod u+x /etc/ssh/keys/test.com/ && chmod o+rx /etc/ssh/keys`
should solve your issue.
While root may enter the directory, I assume that sshd checks the octal permissions to be `0700` or `0755` + `0600` for the authorized_keys file itself. Especially, when `StrictMode yes`.

Without access permission to the directory, and proper permissions the authorized_keys file cannot be read or is being ignored by sshd out of security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -l /etc/ssh/keys
drw------- 2 test.com  test.com   4096 Nov 20 06:53 test.com
drw------- 2 root      root       4096 Nov 20 02:29 root
```

No `x` permission to the directory = no permission to *actually use* anything *inside* the directory. With these permissions, `sshd` would be able to get the directory listing of `/etc/ssh/keys/test.com/` but not able to access the contents of `/etc/ssh/keys/test.com/authorized_keys`.

For `root`, it works because `root` can access anything.